# Add a Upload File function to a custom page in Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I am very new to Shopify and the .liquid format but I want to add a file upload button to a custom contact page on my Shopify site.

Is there a function like this that will populate a upload file option?

```
{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }}
```

I tried replacing ".email" with other logical terms but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. If you want to provide for your customers uploading files for their account, you will have to provide custom code in your theme. A good serviceable pattern is to present them with a file-upload option in their customer account screen, connected to an App you rig for that purpose. It's not hard to do, and it allows you to provide for secure standard CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says to use a jot form. lol.

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/communication/let-customers-upload-files

Here is some documentation for customisation which has the ability to upload files.
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products

This can be done on a cart page. Although because you can make an unlimited number of cart templates it doesn't really have to be a cart. Or you can do it on the product page using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your file upload form.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like Jot will probably be our best solution for the time being.